# Alternatives to create multiple windows if you need to share data among them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I'm working with Electron (javascript and angular) and have two renderer windows, I wanted that renderer 2 displayed some graphs based on data that is present in renderer 1.

However, since sharing objects that contain data and methods between renderers is not possible in Electron, I believe my best/fastest (in implementation) option is to change the 2 renderers option and use instead 2 divs in the same renderer.

Before doing that, I wanted to ask whether there is any other option I am not seeing.

Comment: Do you need the data in renderer 2 change every time renderer 1 change ?

Comment: No, only when the user press the button

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)` and `ipcMain.on(channel, listener)`.

So it's a basic solution:

Set 2 listener on the `Main`

GetDataChannel listener and this listener will send a message to Render 1.

SendDataChannel listener and this listener will send data to Render 2.

When you click on the button send the data with : `ipcRenderer.sendSync()`
On the Render 1 set one `ipcRenderer.sendSync('sendDataChannel','param_optional')`

On the Render 2 set one `ipcRenderer.sendSync('getDataChannel','param_optional')`

Comment: The same problem, not possible to share methods due to the JSON-tranformation

Comment: I don't understand "not possible to share methods due to the JSON-tranformation" ? I will edit my post with more detail.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md

Send a message to the main process asynchronously via channel, you can also send arbitrary arguments. Arguments will be serialized in JSON internally and hence no functions or prototype chain will be included.